# What is the difference between validation and verification in statistical models?

Tags: model-selection, validation

We assume errors in our models are additive and uncorrelated, this is a big hypothesis but we'll assume that it is true. This means that observations have an inherent error $\epsilon_{o}$. Mathematical models have errors due to simplifications $\epsilon_{m}$, our numerical solution has inherent numerical errors $\epsilon_{n}$. So out total error is $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 + \epsilon_m + \epsilon_n$.

I've read somewhere that

> Verification measures the corruption of a solution with respect to
>   the underlying model.

How does this relate to the errors defined above?

In the same manner,

> Validation measures the accuracy of a model to reproduce results.

Are these concepts related to the errors mentioned above? If not, is there a better way to think about them?